# typing "full" using $\mathcal{full}$ gives weird thing?

Tags: mathcal

Just a quick question:

Why is it that when I write `$\mathcal{full}$` the word full is not desplayed at all, instead parenthesis, product and vertical arrows come out? And when I tryed to copy that pdf output and paste it in  this window, the paste result was the word "full"?

Thanks to everyone!

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) many of these special fonts like the cal or the bb only apply to capital letters. Other letters will give *strange* results as it is attempting to grap a letter from a font slot that may not exist.

Comment: The default calligraphic font doesn't have lowercase letters. If you want lowercase, you can change it to one of `boondox`,  `dutchcal`, `esstix` or `bickham` (these are the ones I know).

Comment: with any scripty font set up for math, you will likely get "odd" spacing, especially since this string contains an "f".  indeed, this looks like a word, and if so, you should be using a font designed for text.  if that's the case, you should ask another question highlighting the spacing issue, pointing to this one to show what you've done.